# Group Chart Sorting on Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

The https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/bar_charts/grouped.html link has a good example on how group charts can be implemented in flutter.

However, year and value on the chart are hardcoded into the three groups **desktopSalesData**, **tableSalesData**, and **mobileSalesData**.

My question is how could this be sorted if dynamically data is inserted into these groups ?

To my understanding each group has no knowledge on the other series, so my chart becomes **fifo** instead of sorting.

[image]

Comment: Do you need data from server?

Comment: Data comes from local sqlite database

Comment: Just sort the data before creating the `Series`